# Error "module 'tensorflow.keras' has no attribute '__version__'"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I'm not good at English so I'm sorry for you.
I want to use gpu version keras on M2 mac.
and I followed [this](https://zenn.dev/datasciencekun/articles/74b764515ca246) and installed them.
then I executed its sample code and get the error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 2
      1 from tensorflow import keras
----> 2 keras.__version__

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Mac M2 and I followed this:
https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/
Everything worked fine and I checked the versions with the following:

```
print(f"Tensor Flow Version: {tf.__version__}")
print(f"Keras Version: {tensorflow.keras.__version__}")
```